# ld.so is not able to load the required libraries

Tags: c, gcc

We created a executable of our module using a makefile which has library path details(compiled with -L option).All the required libraries are present int that path and it is set to LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.But Still I am getting the following error while running the executable in dbx.

```
  dbx MsgServer
  For information about new features see `help changes'
  To remove this message, put `dbxenv suppress_startup_message 7.2' in your .dbxrc
  Reading MsgServer
  Reading ld.so.1
  ld.so.1: MsgServer: fatal: libcp.so: open
  failed:       No such file or directory
  terminating signal 9 SIGKILL
```

I am not bale to figure out why the libraries were not linked .Here is the output of the ldd.

```
    ldd MsgServer
    libcp.so =>      (file not found)
    libftux.so =>    (file not found)
    libfldap.so =>   (file not found)
    libfdmq.so =>    (file not found)
    libfbsafe.so =>  (file not found)
    libdmq.so =>     /opt/messageq/lib/libdmq.so
    libmqic.so =>    /usr/lib/libmqic.so
    libsocket.so.1 => /usr/lib/libsocket.so.1
    libc.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/libc.so.1
    libnsl.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
    libdl.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/libdl.so.1
    libCstd.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/libCstd.so.1
    libCrun.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/libCrun.so.1
    libm.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/libm.so.1
    libw.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/libw.so.1
    libthread.so.1 => /usr/lib/libthread.so.1
    libmqmcs.so =>   /usr/lib/libmqmcs.so
    librt.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/librt.so.1
    libmqiz.so =>    /opt/mqm/lib/libmqiz.so
    libmp.so.2 =>    /usr/lib/libmp.so.2
    libaio.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/libaio.so.1
    /usr/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire/lib/libc_psr.so.1
    /usr/lib/cpu/sparcv8plus/libCstd_isa.so.1
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the LD_LIBRARY_PATH exported? Are the libraries in the right directory? Are the libraries compiled with the same ABI and CPU as your app?

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is exported and I am able to see the path when I echo that variable and all the libraries are compiled with same CPU as my app

Comment: Is the binary a SUID (set UID) program?  Or are you running as root?  You seem to be running on Solaris.  Note that LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not work for SUID programs.

Answer (score 0):

Is your LD_LIBRARY_PATH exported? You need to export it.

Comment: however I am able to see those libraries linked to my binary from one user but not able to see them getting linked to my executable from  another user on the same server. path is set to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it is exported in both the user profile files.